# How to pass a object to a popover fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a calendar view and when i hover on a event, i want a pop up which should have all details about that event. Now i have tried giving popover inside my eventRender function which works fine, but i am not able to pass my object to the html view where i have the popover UI.

Here is my popover function:

```
$scope.eventRender = function( event, element, view ) {

element.popover({
title: function () {
return $("#popoverTitle").html();
},
content: function () {
return $("#popoverContent").html();
},
placement: 'bottom',
html: 'true',
trigger: 'hover',
animation: 'true',
container: 'body',
});

// return event;
};
```

Here how to pass my entire event object to the html page.

Comment: what works fine and what doesnt work? can you see your popover? what I can see is that you use ID's but I think you have more then one element in your calendar so you have to uses classes instead (one ID can only be on your page one time).. normaly you would pass your title and content with .html(your_title/your_content);.. you just return empty title and content

Comment: i am able to see my popover with UI, the problem is i wanted to display phone-number address inside that popover which is in my event object. How to access event.phoneNumber value inside the popover

Comment: i think it should work with $("#popoverContent").html("Telefon:"+event.phoneNumber);

Comment: Why are you using jQuery and angular. They both manipulate the Dom and you can have unintended behavior by mixing the two. You can launch a modal and utilize a controller there that captures the dates that you want to pass using a service or you can use $rootScope.$brosdcast and $rootScope.$on to pass data between the controllers.